# Reach my application on google play by name

Tags: android, google-play

I deployed new application to google play, this is the first time for me, I can reach the application through it's link in google play, but when I try to search the app by name it will not display on the search result in google play, the application short and long description contain the application name as well but I still can't find the application by name.

Tags in google play are only predefined so I can't add custom tags, please advice.

Comment: New apps can take a while to be indexed by the store, it will be searchable in a day or 2

Comment: open [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) on your phone and replace **com.android.chrome** with your own **package_name**

Comment: @MichaelStoddart: The application is live on google play since 4 days.

Comment: @Harsh: I can get the app using my application google play link, I want to search for it by name, so other people can reach it by name not using url.

Answer (score 1):

try with **your full application name** is double quote(" ") Play Store Search View

```
"Your application FullName"
```

Or try with your **Application Package Name** like

```
com.xyz.xyz //your package name
```

Comment: yes then try to serach on playstore using your package name

Comment: i means search like com.app.applicationname

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, the application package name already has my application name and searching app in double quote did not workout with me.

Comment: can you provide me your full application name ?

Comment: when I search the application by the full package name I found it, but no one will search like this, I need to find the application by only it's name, the full package name is in English but the application name is in different language, is there anyway else or something I can add to search by specific keyword which is the application name?

Comment: oops! I am not familiar with another way if it is available,kinda Unable to help you :(

Answer (score 1):

You do search and request other people for search in playstore your app like friends and family member for rank your application.2 to 3 days your application listed for search,And you will able to find your application in playstore using you application name.

Comment: I search and ask other people to search by application name (that currently show no result) or by application full URL?